# Error in writing a function in Java - the returned type fits the one written in the header yet it says there is a mismatch

Tags: java, methods, matrix, type-mismatch

I've written a method in Java that recieves two integers and allows the user to insert numbers into it. The method should return the matrix filled by numbers. This is the code I've written:

```
public static int[][] InputMat(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] matrixA = new int[rows][cols];
    int i,j;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert the numbers into the matrix");
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            matrixA[i][j] = s.nextInt();
        }
        return matrixA;
    }enter code here
```

Then I got an error which sayed that the method must return a result of type int[][] but this is what I wrote. Any suggestions? + would you write this method otherwise?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement is currently inside of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Put your return statement at the end of your method.

```
public static int[][] InputMat(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] matrixA = new int[rows][cols];
    int i,j;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert the numbers into the matrix");
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            matrixA[i][j] = s.nextInt();
        }
        //return matrixA;
    }
    return matrixA;
}
```

This is necessary (a) To satisfy the compiler, (b) For correctly building your return object.  If the method returned where you have first put the statement, then only the first row would be populated (that is the i=0 case would be the only one to execute)

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is in the wrong place: It's inside your outer `for`, and so the compiler doesn't think that all paths return a `int[][]`.